# Perl script to parse a text file and match a string

Tags: perl

I'm editing my question to add more details

The script executes the command and redirects the output to a text file.

The script then parses the text file to match the following string " Standard  1.1.1.1"

The output in the text file is :

```
             Host Configuration
             ------------------

             Profile              Hostname
             --------             ---------

             standard             1.1.1.1
             standard             1.1.1.2
```

The code works if i search for either 1.1.1.1 or standard . When i search for standard 1.1.1.1 together the below script fails.

this is the error that i get "Unable to find string: standard 172.25.44.241 at testtest.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SSH::Expect;     
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open (HOSTRULES, ">hostrules.txt") || die "could not open output file";
my $hos = $ssh->exec(" I typed the command here  ");
print HOSTRULES ($hos);
close(HOSTRULES);

sub find_string
{
my ($file, $string) = @_;
open my $fh, '<', $file;
while (<$fh>) {
    return 1 if /\Q$string/;
}
die "Unable to find string: $string";
}

find_string('hostrules.txt', 'standard 1.1.1.1');
```

Comment: Please define "Thrown and error"  what do you expect to happen when it is not found?

Comment: I have added my updated script below.The script throws the following error.   ""Name "main::OUTPUTFILE" used only once: possible typo at sm.pl line 19.
 Unable to find string: Object-cache at sm.pl line 27."

Comment: You are using a fancy electric screwdriver to pound nails to a board. `input_record_separator` is not meant to be used for matching.

Comment: 1) pedantically, the "used only once" message is a warning, and not an error. 2) there are not 27 lines of code in your sample. I count 11.

Comment: @len Jaffe, I have added more details to the question.Could you please take a look at it and let me know what needs to be done?

Comment: @user3587025 - Please don't do these kind of edits. Your question has nothing to do with the original question. Your problem is a simple issue with the regular expression used.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps write a function:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

sub find_string {
    my ($file, $string) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    while (<$fh>) {
        return 1 if /\Q$string/;
    }
    die "Unable to find string: $string";
}

find_string('output.txt', 'object-cache enabled');
```

Or just slurp the entire file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $data = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'output.txt';
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

die "Unable to find string" if $data !~ /object-cache enabled/;
```

Comment: I have posted my code above.I'm using the function that you provided. The script fails, when i integrated the function with my code.

Comment: For the function that you have provided ,how do I test the negative case. I mean I would like to check if the string is NOT present in the text file. say for example i want to check that the the string "object-cache enabled" is NOT_PRESENT in the file output.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne '/object-cache enabled/ and $found++; END{ print "Object cache disabled\n" unless $found}' < input_file
```

This just reads the file a line at a time; if we find the key phrase, we increment `$found`. At the end, after we've read the whole file, we print the message unless we found the phrase.

If the message is insufficient, you can `exit 1 unless $found` instead.

I suggest this because there are two things to learn from this:

1. Perl provides good tools for doing basic filtering and data munging right at the command line.
2. Sometimes a simpler approach gets a solution out better and faster.

This absolutely isn't the perfect solution for every possible data extraction problem, but for this particular one, it's just what you need.

The `-ne` option flags tell Perl to set up a `while` loop to read all of standard input a line at a time, and to take any code following it and run it into the middle of that loop, resulting in a 'run this pattern match on each line in the file' program in a single command line.

`END` blocks can occur anywhere and are always run at the end of the program only, so defining it inside the `while` loop generated by `-n` is perfectly fine. When the program runs out of lines, we fall out the bottom of the `while` loop and run out of program, so Perl ends the program, triggering the execution of the END block to print (or not) the warning.

If the file you are searching contained a string that indicated the cache was disabled (the condition you want to catch), you could go even shorter:

```
perl -ne '/object-cache disabled/ and die "Object cache disabled\n"' < input_file
```

The program would scan the file only until it saw the indication that the cache was disabled, and would exit abnormally at that point.

Comment: How to parse a text file and check if the string is not present ?

Comment: The first example is a "fail if I didn't find X"; second is a "fail if I found something I didn't want".

Answer (score 0):

You're scanning a file for a particular string. If that string is **not** found in that file, you want an error thrown. Sounds like a job for [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use features qw(say);
use autodie;

use constant {
    OUTPUT_FILE   => 'output.txt',
    NEEDED_STRING => "object-cache enabled",
};

open my $out_fh, "<", OUTPUT_FILE;
my @output_lines = <$out_fh>;
close $out_fh;
chomp @output_lines;

grep { /@{[NEEDED_STRING]}/ } @output_lines  or
    die qq(ERROR! ERROR! ERROR!);    #Or whatever you want
```

The `die` command will end the program and exit with a non-zero exit code. The error will be printed on STDERR.

I don't know why, but using `qr(object-cache enabled),` and then `grep { NEEDED_STRING }` didn't seem to work. Using `@{[...]}` allows you to interpolate constants.

Instead of constants, you might want to be able to pass in the error string and the name of the file using [GetOptions](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

I used the old fashion `<...>` file handling instead of `IO::File`, but that's because I'm an old fogy who learned Perl back in the 20th century before it was cool. You can use `IO::File` which is probably better and more modern.

---

## ADDENDUM

> Any reason for slurping the entire file in memory? -  Leonardo Herrera

As long as the file is reasonably sized (say 100,000 lines or so), reading the entire file into memory shouldn't be that bad. However, you could use a loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use features qw(say);
use autodie;

use constant {
    OUTPUT_FILE   => 'output.txt',
    NEEDED_STRING => qr(object-cache enabled),
};

open my $out_fh, "<", OUTPUT_FILE;
my $output_string_found;   # Flag to see if output string is found

while ( my $line = <$out_fh> ) {
    if ( $line =~ NEEDED_STRING ){
        $output_string_found = "Yup!"
        last;   # We found the string. No more looping.
    }
}
die qq(ERROR, ERROR, ERROR) unless $output_string_found;
```

This will work with the constant `NEEDED_STRING` defined as a quoted regexp.

Comment: Any reason for slurping the entire file in memory?

Comment: No reason except it allows me to use `grep` and keep the program simple. Otherwise, I'd do a loop while reading each line. If the output file isn't too large (Let's say less than 100,000 lines), slurping the file should be okay.

Comment: I just tested to see if `grep` works with a file handle. Nope.

Comment: Added to my answer to not use `grep` and slurp up the whole file.

Comment: Yeah, the second example contains a small error (a leftover from your first example). I think the second answer is the correct approach (I used the same idea in my answer.)

Comment: The first answer is easier to understand. I can see I am _grepping_ for a particular string in my output, and if it isn't there, I throw an error. The second answer takes a bit longer to perceive what is going on. Back in the old days when computer memory was measured in kilobytes, you tried to be as efficient as possible. Now, I rather error on the side of maintainability. If it takes five seconds longer for a developer to figure out the second way over the first, I've lost whatever efficiency I gained.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see it that way. You are doing something already strange (`my @output_lines = <$out_fh>;`) which is already a *Perlism*; if you can understand it, you definitely can understand reading a line at a time (without mentioning that almost all of the introductory tutorials to Perl teach you to read line by line from a file handle!)

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using `Net::SSH::Expect`? Are you executing a remote command? If not, all you need to execute a program and wait for its completion is [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

```
system("cmd > file.txt") or die "Couldn't execute: $!";
```

Second, it appears that what fails is your regular expression. You are searching for the literal expression `standard 1.1.1.1` but in your sample text it appears that the wanted string contains either tabs or several spaces instead of a single space. Try changing your call to your `find_string` function:

```
find_string('hostrules.txt', 'standard\s+1.1.1.1'); # note '\s+' here
```

Comment: I'm using Net::SSH::Expect as i need to login to a cisco router to execute the commands.  and '\s+' isn't working. I tried. any other suggestions ?